# Module pattern $.bind not working

Tags: javascript

Im new to the javascript module pattern and can't get something like this to work, am I missing something? The $.bind don't give any errors and dropBox is not NULL.

```
 var Application = (function(d, w, $) {

    var drop, dragStart, dragEnter, dragOver, dragLeave;

    drop = function(e) {
    };

    dragStart = function(e) {
    };

    dragEnter = function(e) {
    };

    dragOver = function(e) { 
    };

    dragLeave = function(e) {  
    };

    return {

        init: function() {

            var dropBox = $('#someid');
            dropBox.bind('dragstart', dragStart);
            dropBox.bind('dragenter', dragEnter);
            dropBox.bind('dragover', dragOver);
            dropBox.bind('drop', drop);
            dropBox.bind('dragleave', dragLeave);
        }
    };

})(document, window, window.jQuery);
```

Comment: Did you call `Application.init()`?

Comment: Yes using (function() { }());

Comment: with jquery `dropBox` won't be null, it could be empty if its not in a dom ready state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `(function(...) {})(...);` you're only calling the declared function which returns an object with an `init()` member. As long as you don't call the `init()` member function, nothing will happen.

You should call `Application.init()` in the document ready event:

```
$(function() {
    Application.init();
});
```

If you call it too early, `$('#someid')` will be empty.

Besides that, there's nothing wrong with the code in your question. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BXRMF/)

Comment: Yes I can assure you that Application.init() is called.

Comment: "Yes using (function() { }());", I got plenty of console.log in the real code and init is executed

Comment: @user1655758 that isn't a dom ready scope. please show context around when you call `init`.

Comment: Ah, changed to code so Application.init() is called within window.onload = function... and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: @user1655758 don't use `window.onload`, use the jQuery way as demonstrated in my answer